# UI elements moving with the HoloLensCamera prefab by default

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a basic scene with 3 prefabs from the `HoloToolkit-Unity` package:
`HololensCamera` + `InputManager` + `CursorWithFeedback`

I then add a `Canvas` (and subsequently a `Panel` and a `Button`) to my scene, with the `Canvas` being in `Screen Space - Camera` and the `HololensCamera` being the `Render Camera` and of course everything was fine, until I noticed that when I run on device, the cube is there as a fixed game object (as one would expect!) but my whole `Canvas` seems like it is attached to the camera.

Why is this? How do I place a fixed `Canvas` in my scene?

Comment: Any luck after reading manual or you still need assistance?

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq Thanks for following up. Just finished reading now. I got my answer. many thanks.

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq I still do not understand one little thing... If in the `WorldSpace` render mode, the Canvas will behave as any other object in the scene, why can I not re-size it like any other object? In code, I get the initial size via `canvasWidth  = myCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;` and then somewhere else I multiply that by 2 though this never takes effect...

Comment: open a new question with the code related to that question.

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq Hi again, I have resolved my issues, but with my UI Canvas in WorldSpace mode, I am having a new problem. I thought I would just send you the link, if you could possibly help please. Thanks, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563636/adjust-canvas-menu-size-and-scale-in-a-holoworld)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through this
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html

Notice the differences between Overlay/Screenspace/Worldspace

And also try to understand the relation between different camera's and UI elements. If afterwards you still don't understand i'll try to help you.