# Adjust Canvas Menu Size and Scale in a HoloWorld

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, camera, hololens

The following script is supposed to enlarge a `UI Canvas` menu in the world space, so as the user gets far, the menu grows in size and scale, and as the user approaches it, it shrinks proportionately.

We are actually trying to update the height of the menu to the camera's frustum height, so that the menu always takes up exactly the vertical height of the camera's view.

Is this the way towards a solution? What are we doing wrong that the new size does not match the cam' frustum height? We have put this script on the `HoloLensCamera` in out app's scene...

```
public class Adjuster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform _rectTransform;
    private float _ratio;
    private float _pixPerUnit = 100f;
    private Vector3 _gazeOrigin;
    private Vector3 _uiOrigin;
    private float _frustumHeight;
    private float _distance;
    public bool _reSizeCanvas;
    private Camera _camera;
    private float _canvasWidth;
    private float _canvasHeight;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (_reSizeCanvas)
        {          
            Vector2 initialSize = _rectTransform.sizeDelta;
            _ratio = _rectTransform.rect.width / _rectTransform.rect.height;
        }
    }    

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        _gazeOrigin = transform.position;
        _uiOrigin = _rectTransform.position;
        _distance = Vector3.Distance(_gazeOrigin, _uiOrigin);
        _frustumHeight = 2.0f * _distance * Mathf.Tan( this.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad );    
        _rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(_ratio * _frustumHeight * _pixPerUnit, _frustumHeight * _pixPerUnit);
    }   
}
```

Comment: If u are not keeping the original distance u start at,and the original size of canvas how are u making a ratio and applying it then then?

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq I use the `_distance` between holocam and menu canvas to calculate the frustum height, so as distance changes, the frustum height changes and so the canvas should adapt to that. I don't want the distance between the two to remain the same. I mean I don't want the menu to walk after the user. I just want it to grow in size if the user walks away. Is this what you mean?

Comment: What i am asking is since u are scaling compared to something u need baseline to compare it to. since u are scaling of distance u a need baseline distance to compare it to. are you doing that?

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq I "think" I know what you mean... Something like "initialDistanceToCamera" as a baseline for distance, similar to initial menu height as a baseline for new height?

Comment: Exactly because i don't see that in your code. once you have that compare them to each other to get a ratio. apply that ratio to the original size of canvas. Be aware that if u don't put limits the canvas might get really large when running away3

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept the solution, or write your own answer(if you figured out another solution) so the Question can be closed.

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq Hi Jeroen, I have not tried it yet, due to other holo tasks. I will, as soon as I can... Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying a ratio to something. That ratio is calculated based on the comparison of two things. In this case u are comparing the distance between u and the menu to a baseline distance between u and the menu. So u need fixed distance to compare your actual distance to.

A frustum is literally A cone like shape that the camera spawns (with the tip starting at the camera) and it will render anything that is inside this cone. Its dimensions will always be the same if u don't mess with the camera. If u want to get frustum height involved u need to find out where the object is in that cone. Then find out the dimensions of that slice of the cone.

The easiest solution;
Leave the frustum height out of this and your solution is very easy; Player gets closer increase scale. Vice Versa

Comment: Did you have any luck with this solution or still not the desired effect?

Comment: I thought about your suggestion. I think since `_distance` is constantly used in calculating and updating the frustum height, its change is already taken into account as a baseline. The frustum calc starts with the initial distance and is continuously updated as the cam gets farther... Since I am not trying to tag-along or bill-board, I am not sure if I need that kinda base-line comparison.  Let me know please if you agree.  Also, there is another little question in my post, if you could tell me what you think about that too please. Cheers

Comment: Are u changing the camera's frustum at any point throughout the game? I think u are making stuff really complicated by getting frustum height involved. The frustum is how the camera deals with the world i do not think u should be doing anything in there game-size related.

Comment: Not changing the camera's frustum at any point. Only moving it backward (as if the user is backing up) so it is not the frustum height that is being changed. It is the canvas size that is being set to the frustum height (which is calculated in LateUpdate).

Comment: If your frustum height is not being changed then you are basically loading same value over and over, why do you insist on using frustum, what benefit are you getting from doing it that way?

Comment: Leave the frustum height out of this and your solution is very easy; Player gets closer increase scale. Vice Versa

Comment: You are right. Changing scale  based on distance is a better solution. Copy this into your answer and I shall happily mark it as the answer!  Many thanks for your help.